# Is there anyway for Applemail to save all attachments and to be able to export it?

Tags: mail.app

I recently just finished graduate school and so my university has told me that I am to have the mail account disabled. They further suggested that I download all mail so that I don't lose any precious email threads I had. So today I downloaded all my mail onto my applemail client and exported the mailbox so that I had a copy. However, to my chagrin, I realized that most of the attachments inside the mailbox were not fully downloaded. It seems that the only way an attachment in an email would download completely is if I clicked on it. However, with 20 thousand emails, this isnt really a suitable option. Does anyone know of any way to have all my attachments downloaded so that I have an exact copy of my mailbox sitting somewhere? thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you talk to the IT Department at your School to see if they can assist with that.

Comment: Could you edit this to explain how your Mail is served? gmail? IMAP? POP? Exchange? - there might be a better tool for the job than Mail.app, but listing your settings will help us help you. I've never not seen attachments download - so perhaps the server details are relevant to that.